# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component when loading file from app storage - Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to retrieve a file from my Application folder, but I face this exception:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

I tried to move the file out of Assets folder and locate it in the root folder, but I receive the same problem!

Here's my code:

```
try
{
    StorageFile data = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx://Assets/data.json"));
    //...
}
catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(exception);
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your file uri, you have to put another slash '/' in this part of the uri `ms-appx:///`, Your code will be like this:

```
try
            {
                StorageFile data = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/data.json"));
                //...
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception);
            }
```

And, Make sure you set `Content` in the `Build Action` in the file properties menu, otherwise you'll face a `FileNotFoundException` :).